# What happens when wait() is called on an object not extending Thread or implements Runnable?

Tags: java, multithreading

What happens when wait() is called on an object not extending Thread or implements Runnable?

This is such simple question but when I was asked by somebody I had OK but not exact answer. Any exact answers?

Comment: You basically calling the `wait` in the main thread that is created in when you start the program.

Comment: Why do you think `wait()` has anything with `Thread` objects to do? It sounds like you've fundamentally misunderstood what it does; what is it that you think it does?

Comment: You can wait() on any object, it does not have to be a thread/runable. In fact it is bad practice to do so anyway. The only thing you always need to do is to hold the monitor for that object (you typically do that by running it inside a  `synchronized(o)` { o.wait(); }` block. The only shortcut to that is a synchronized method, which holds the lock on the instance (which is the runable).

Comment: Do not wait/notify on thread objects, they use the monitor internally, so you might get unexpected behavior (early wakeups or swalled notifications).

Comment: I don't think `wait` does what you think it does.

Answer (score 1):

The [java docs](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/Object.html#notify()) are pretty clear on this.  It does as the names suggest, causes the current thread to wait until notify or notifyall is called on the object (by another thread).  These methods are used to *coordinate* between Threads that need access to the same critical resources and need mutual exclusion.  In depth discussion [here](https://www.artima.com/insidejvm/ed2/threadsynchP.html).

Calling wait and notify on a Thread object only makes sense if that Thread is being used as the lock object, which would be unusual in my experience.

Comment: It is also worth mentioning that after a `Thread` calls  `wait()` on an object, that `Thread`will release the object's lock which makes it possible for other threads to synchronize on that object.

Comment: @Titus, To be more precise, the `o.wait()` method releases the lock on object `o` before waiting, and then it re-acquires the lock before returning.   A lot of these noobs don't understand the difference between a `Thread` (i.e., an instance of the Thread class) and a thread (i.e., an execution of the code).  The way you said it would be understood by any experienced developer, but it doesn't help the noobs.

Answer (score 0):

It still works. You're just calling wait on the main thread that is running.

According to the [Javadocs](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/Object.html)

> void  wait()
>   Causes the current thread to wait until another thread invokes the notify() method or the notifyAll() method for this object.

The reason they're not in the thread class is to give all objects some availability for concurrency control. You might want your object communicating with another thread(s)

Answer (score 0):

wait will work ona thread as with any other object with one difference - when a thread terminates the notifyAll method is invoked on this thread and wait will suddenly terminate. It is not recommended to use a Thread as a lock

Comment: A program should _always_ be prepared for the case where wait() returns before the event happens for which the caller was waiting.  That happens often in multi-consumer situations where a notifyAll() wakes all of the consumers, and one consumer claims the event while the others go back to waiting.  Also, the Java Language Spec allows wait() to return even when nobody has called notify() or notifyAll().  That's called a _spurious_ wakeup, and it can happen in some JVM implementations.

Answer (score 0):

It will work.The Current thread (main) will wait till the mentioned value.

For example check the below program:

```
public class Test{
  public static void main(String[] args)
   {  
     try{
        Test t = new Test();
          synchronized (t){
          System.out.println("Will wait for 10 secs");
          t.wait(10000);
          System.out.println("Wait over");
          }
        }
        catch (Exception e){
        System.out.println(e);
        }        
    }
}
```

Output:
Will wait for 10 secs
Wait over-----> Will be printed after 10 secs

Answer (score -2):

OK. So I just took the liberty to run and see it myself.
If wait() is called on any object which is not in a Syncronized context will throw IllegalMonitorStateException.

```
public class HelloWorld{

  public static void main(String []args){
      try{

         String str = new String();
         str.wait();
     }catch(InterruptedException e){
         System.out.println(e);
     }catch(IllegalMonitorStateException e){
         System.out.println(e);
     }
    System.out.println("Hello World");
 }
}
```

Output : java.lang.IllegalMonitorStateException
Hello World

Comment: `String str = new String(); synchronized(str) {str.wait();}` will happily wait for the next 234days or less or more.

Comment: I don't see that this is an answer. If you want to update the question, then you should edit it.

Comment: @Dolda2000 My questions was simply what will happen if I call wait() on a simple non-thread object . The simple answer was it will throw IllegalMonitorStateException, and that's what I showed with code. With synchronized context I meant,  as ANY object can be used as LOCK object or MUTEX. If a program use this object as lock  using synchronized block   , In that scenario if some thread calls this code , then it will use Monitor of this lock object and NOW it can call wait() (i.e  str.wait() ) without IllegalMonitorStateException , because now we are using it in Synchronized context.

Comment: I don't see any reason to down vote the result of simple java program output.

Comment: This is not an answer to the question. You asked what will happen when you're calling it on "on an object not extending Thread or implements Runnable". However not synchronizing before calling `wait` always causes this exception no matter whether it's on a Thread or Runnable. Actually, there *is* no different no matter what object you call it on.

Comment: I may not have clearly stated my question, but if wait() is available in Object method and my question was what will happen if wait() be called on this object so answer should be "Program will throw exception and you should synchronize it before calling wait()"  and that program showed , and that's what answered my question.

Comment: @supernova, but that is no different from when calling it on a `Thread` object.